# Getting approximate value for variable instead of exact value

Tags: python

I'm getting approximate values for **start** variable in below code:

```
start = 1
end = 2
incr = 0.2
while start < end:
    print(start)
    start = start + incr
```

Actual output:
1
1.2
1.4
1.5999999999999999
1.7999999999999998
1.9999999999999998
Hit any key to close this window...

Expected output:
1
1.2
1.4
1.6
1.8

I couldn't figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
start = 1
end = 2
incr = 0.2
while start < end:
    print(start)
    start = round(start + incr,1)
```